# Guava Optional. How to use the correct

Tags: java, guava, option-type

I have a class

```
private class TouchCommand {
  private int action;
  private int x;
  private int y;
...
```

When the command is executed, it is necessary to verify the field values ​​- null / not null, and depending on it to produce longitudinal action. I want to use Options from Google Guava.

Which solution is right?
this:

```
public boolean executeCommand() {
  Optional<Integer> optionalAction = Optional.fromNullable(action);
  ...
```

or:

```
private class TouchCommand {
  private Optional<Integer> action;
  private Optional<Integer> x;
  private Optional<Integer> y;
...
```

Given that the call to parseAction may also return a null (or absent):

```
TouchCommand touchCommand = new TouchCommand();
touchCommand.mAction = parseAction(xmlParser.getAttributeValue(namespace, "action"));
...
```

Questions:

1. whether or not to do so: the method parseAction (and similar) returns Optional ?
2. whether or not to do so: the field of class objects Optional ?
3. whether or not to do so: when checking the fields of the class (assuming that they can be null) to convert them into objects Optional ?

Thx.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Guava contributor here...

Any or all of these things are fine, but some of them may be overkill.

Generally, as discussed in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9561334/869736), `Optional` is primarily used for two things: to make it clearer what you would've *meant* by `null`, and in method return values to make sure the caller takes care of the "absent" case (which it's easier to forget with `null`).  We *certainly* don't advocate replacing every nullable value  with an `Optional` everywhere in your code -- we certainly don't do that within Guava itself!

A lot of this will have to be your decision -- there's no universal rule, it's a relatively subjective judgement, and I don't have enough context to determine what I'd do in your place -- but based on what context you've provided, I'd consider making the methods return `Optional`, but probably wouldn't change any of the other fields or anything.

Comment: I just thought to do a class field "Optional" is not correct. If this is also correct, then (I think) to store values ​​that can be null, is easier than converting each time value in the Optional, if needed verification.

Comment: I mean, it's not like it wouldn't work.  But `Optional` carries overhead of its own that might not be desirable.  It's really much better to optimize for maintainability and code readability here.