# Unwrapping a Guava Optional in a single expression

Tags: java, guava

As a Scala developer who also works in `GWT`, I welcome the addition of `Optional` to Guava.

One of our most common use cases of `Optional` is when returning optional values from methods (as suggested by the answer to [What's the point of Guava's Optional class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561295/whats-the-point-of-guavas-optional-class).

In scala, I often write code like this:

```
def someExpensiveOperation(params: Type): Option[ResultType] = ...
someExpensiveOperation(params).foreach({ val =>
  doSomethingWithVal (val)
})
```

Guava's Option does not seem to allow anything more elegant than something like this:

```
Optional<MyType> optionalResponse = someExpensiveOperation(params);
if (optionalResponse.isPresent()) {
    doSomethingWithVal(optionalResponse.get())
}
```

The local variable is redundant, and it requires repeating a pattern which could be abstracted  (the `if (optional.isPresent()) { doSomethingWith(optional.get()) }` ).

The other option would be to call the method which returns an `Optional` twice:

```
if (someExpensiveOperation(params).isPresent()) {
    doSomethingWithVal(someExpensiveOperation(params).get())
}
```

But that is clearly undesirable, since it invoked an expensive operation multiple times unnecessarily.

I'm curious how other people have handled this very-common case (perhaps by writing a static utility method like `<T>useIfPresent(Optional<T> val, Closure<? super T> closure)`?) or if anyone has found more elegant solutions.

Also, if anyone knows why a method like `Optional.foreach(Closure<? super T> closure)` (but hopefully better named) was omitted, I would be curious to hear the rationale.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not there because we feel the anonymous class awkwardness of writing a Closure is more awkward and less readable -- at least in Java, not necessarily in Scala -- than the local variable and the if statement that you've already written.

That said, another alternative is

```
for (Foo x : someExpensiveOperation().asSet()) {
  // do stuff with x
}
```

Note that `asSet` is necessary here -- `Optional` very deliberately does not itself implement `Iterable`.

Comment: A little OT, but I'm wondering why `Optional.asSet()` returns `Set` instead of `ImmutableSet` since it's documented to return immutable one. Is it because `Optional` is shipped in `c.g.c.base` and not in `c.g.c.collect`?

Comment: That's exactly it.  (Google's build system more or less forbids cyclic package dependencies.)

Comment: That's perfectly reasonable. I often struggle with the inherent conflict between doing things in what feels like a clean functional way, and Java's lack of closures. That being said, I use IntelliJ which automatically collapses anonymous inner classes into the JDK 8-style closure syntax. Along those lines, are there plans to revisit anonymous-class-verbosity-based design decisions when Java 8 is closer to shipping?

Comment: Revisit?  Perhaps.  Google is still in the process of moving to JDK7, let alone 8; we have many users who will be on JDK 5 for the forseeable future.  We'll see what happens.

Comment: JDK 5? That's too bad. Guava's tagline is "Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java 1.6+" :)

Comment: We maintain a separate backport for JDK5 users nowadays.  (But e.g. many of our users are Android apps which need Froyo compatibility, which is comparable to JDK5.)