# How to avoid write code like "XXX!=null" or "XXX!=null || XXX.isEmpty"

Tags: java, database-design

I am writing codes that query the database to get the data. There are some classes that consist of `List`s, but sometime the list or other attribute can not be initiated and their value is `null`, so I need to write `list!=null || list.isEmpty` or `attribute != null`, before I can use the attribute.

Unfortunately, it easy to forget it, and I really think it is ugly to do it every time when I operate an attribute. I am going to write some code to explain it.

```
public class SpotVo {
    private Double avg;

    private String brief;

    private ArrayList<HotelVo> hotels;

    private int id;

    private ArrayList<byte[]> images;

    private AddressVo location;

    private String name;

    private ArrayList<RestaurantVo> restaurants;
}
```

As you can see, there are some lists and other attributes in this class, there can all be `null` or empty, can I do something to avoid it?

Comment: I think the best way to avoid this kind of ugly code is to always write short, simple, concise methods that only perform one basic task.  If you do this, you can generally perform one clean null-check at the top of each method and exit immediately if something important is null.  I had a professor in school that told us "_every function you write should be less than 60 lines_".  That was some of the best advice I ever got.

Comment: @jahroy *"every method should be less than 60 lines"* amen, brother.

Comment: I have learned an other edition that kick a man who write a method has 10 lines out of you term.

Comment: @ssj ^^ I wish I could make sense out of that comment...

Comment: @jahroy - You might be happier if you don't understand it.

Comment: @HotLicks can't agree more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on whether `null` has a special meaning.  For example for a `String` field does your application need to distinguish between `null` and `""`?  For a `Collection`-valued field does it need to distinguish between `null` and an empty collection object?

If the answer is "no", then you could write your "data object" classes to normalize the nulls to the respective "in band" values.  You could do this in the getters or the setters or the constructors, depending on exactly how the objects are materialized from the database.

A couple of other things you could do are:

- Change the database schema to make the respective columns "not null".
- If you are using an ORM or a data binding mechanism, try to configure that (via annotations or whatever) to use the "in band" values instead of `null`.

The point of turning `null` into `""` or an empty array or collection is that you don't need to treat the "in band" value as a special case ... unless the business logic of your application specifically requires this.

In short, if you stamp out the `null` values systematically, you don't need to test for them in the business logic.

---

Note that this approach doesn't always work.  The case that annoys me is fetching parameters from an `HTTPRequest` object in a servlet:

- The application potentially has to deal with 4 distinct cases:

  - parameter not present
  - parameter present with no value / an empty value
  - parameter present with a non-empty value
  - parameter present multiple times.
- The parameters are being fetched from a standard API rather than a custom class that could be made to normalize the values according to the webapp's requirements.

Comment: I think you are right,I should control it from the source.

Comment: I think that too since this technique will save you from sending  objects or nulls for no reason in case if nulls or "" for Strings

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this is with [CollectionUtils.isEmpty](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.util.Collection%29).

> Returns: true if empty or null

This way you can do it in one line.

When it comes to "attributes", there are design patterns that can help with this.  Or, you can use [Guava's Optional](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) class.  You can read more about it here: [What's the point of Guava's Optional class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561295/whats-the-point-of-guavas-optional-class)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that checks if an object is `null` and/or if it's a String, is it `""`.  Then simply call that function each time you would need to check all of the conditions.  Make it return a boolean so that you can just insert it in the `if` statements.

```
boolean check(Object o)
{
    if (o != null)
        {
            if (o instanceof String)
            {
                if (((String) o).equals(""))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Refer to rcook's suggestion in the comments for a better implementation of this.

Comment: but I can not write a function for every class that i used in my app.

Comment: check my edit.  It will work for all Objects (all of your defined classes implicitly extend Object).  If you have any other special cases for specific Objects, other than String, you can insert them in the function.

Comment: Instead of using instanceof, have one method for Object and one for String.  Let the compiler decide which one to call and save your runtime an if statement...  boolean isEmpty(Object o) { return (o == null); }  (something additional needed for collections)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's two problems here:
One is that you have to check for `null` values which I absolutely agree is stupid. The problem is that `null` is a native to the Java language, so the only way to make it slightly nicer is to use methods like the ones mentioned by Steve P and tieTYT. There is however another way of dealing with null by *never using it*. Of course you cannot completely avoid it, but at least in your own code you should eliminate all `null`-references. There are a few great arguments for that which I won't cover here, but you can read [Avoiding != null statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java) for more details.

If you're interested a Java-based language, Scala, have developed this nicely by implementing an Option class that can tell whether a value exists or does not (equal to the `null` value). Nice blog post about it here: http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.fr/2008/10/avoiding-nulls.html

Having (mostly) stowed the null-issue away, the next problem will be to check for `isEmpty` or similar when using collections. This is, as you say, a pain in the arse. But I've actually found that these checks can be largely avoided. It all depends on what you need to do with your collection of course, but in most cases collections are used for traversing or manipulation in some way. Using the foreach-loop in Java will make sure nothing is performed if nothing is in the collection. Neat.

There are some cases where a collection must not be empty. Some of these can be avoided though, by having a good design (for instance one that allows empty lists, ensures that no list are empty etc.), but, for the rest of them there are simply no way around. Ever. But, having eliminated the null-checks, calling a few `isEmpty` now and then isn't that bad :-)

Hope that helped.