# How to save null value in Guava Optional

Tags: java, guava

I am new to Guava library.

I am trying to use Optional in my method arguments. One problem I found is that I cannot possibly pass null value into Optional.

I think the purpose of introducing Optional is to differentiate

1. Something that does not have a value
2. Something that has a null value

For example, Optional.absent() means the value does not exist. While null is a value that exist.

With this logic, I assume Optional must have some way to allow us to save a null value in it. However, I could not find a way to do this.

My method is defined as:

```
void myMethod(Optional<String> arguments) {
    ....
}
```

If I use

```
myMethod(Optional.of(null));
```

It will give me the runtime error says the value cannot be null.

How can I possibly pass null inside an Optional?

Comment: You are completely missing `Optional`'s point, please read [UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained page from Guava Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained). Generally `Optional` is **not** meant to be used in method arguments but as a result.

Comment: @Xaerxess where does it say that `Optional` is not meant to be used in method arguments?

Comment: @milkplusvellocet 1) While introducing `Optional` to Java 8 [there has been a big discussion about this](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-June/010024.html): should`Optional` be treated as `OptionalResult`? 2) please read Oracle's [Brian Goetz summary on this topic](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-October/006365.html). 3) [Guava devs also does not recommend using `Optional` in this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9561334/708434): _we recommend that you use Optional as a return type for your methods, but not necessarily in your method arguments._

Comment: @Xaerxess true that the Guava devs don't actively recommend it - perhaps OP has a good reason to use it in this way though.

Comment: The main reason that `Optional` doesn't make sense as a parameter is that there are better ways of making a parameter optional: primarily, creating an overload of the method that simply does not take the parameter.

Comment: Is `Optional` in Java 8 or `Guava` specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an intentional restriction.

`Optional` is an implementation of [the **Maybe monad**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type). This is intended to replace nulls in a type-safe way, guaranteeing that if the option value is present, you won't get a `NullPointerException` when you try to use it. Allowing you to insert `null` would break this type-safety guarantee.

If you really need to distinguish two kinds of "no data" value, consider using `Optional<Optional<String>>` instead (wrapping your inner possibly-null data in an `Option<String>` by using `Optional.fromNullable`).

Comment: It's not fully parametric so I wouldn't say it forms a Monad. Not allowing the insertion of `null` actually breaks type-safety (exactly because we do a non-parametric `null` check).

Answer (score 1):

See [**JavaDoc**](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html)

> An immutable object that may contain a non-null reference to another
> object. Each instance of this type either contains a non-null
> reference, or contains nothing (in which case we say that the
> reference is "absent"); it is never said to "contain `null`".
>
> [...]

Answer (score 1):

Use `Optional.fromNullable(T nullableReference)`

Comment: This creates an absent Optional, not an Optional that contains a null value as asked in the question.

Comment: @Dušan what would an Optional that contains a null value look like?

Comment: to put it simply `Optional.fromNullable(null)` is the same as `Optional.absent()`

Comment: right, but you mentioned before that my answer results in an absent Optional, not an Optional that contains a null value. But the two are equivalent, so I'm not sure what your point was?

Comment: My point is that Optional can never contain a null value. Consider that  `Optional.fromNullable(null).get()` will throw an exception, it will not return null.

Comment: agreed. i never claimed it would return null. the original question asked "how can I pass nulls inside an Optional" which I answered. your original comment seemed to suggest I didn't answer the question...

Answer (score -1):

From [this wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained) from google/guava repo, you should use

```
Optional.absent()
```

@Dušan already wrote it in a comment to another answer, but I guess this way it will be easier to be found by other people